# Pandas CSV Move first row to header row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header

I have this table which i export to CSV Using this code:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype("datetime64").dt.date
df = df.set_index("time")
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.to_csv(r'C:\****\Exports\exportMMA.csv', index=False)
```

While exporting this, my result is:

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| time | BufTF2 | BufTF3 |
| 12/12/2022 | 10 | 150 |

I want to get rid of column 1,2,3 and replace the header with BufFT2 and BufFT3

Tried this :

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
```

And This :

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Somehow it wont work, I not realy in need to replace the headers in the dataframe having the right headers in csv is more important.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your initial CSV file has a header or you want to also create one with Pandas?

Comment: I'm loading data from dataframe into an CSV the original dataframe has the header on the right place but after manupilating the data i creates default header names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try rename:

```
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me end up with these errors :   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5943, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5857, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique

Answer (score 0):

when loading the input file you can specify which row to use as the header

```
pd.read_csv(inputfile,header=1)  # this will use the 2nd row in the file as column titles
```

Comment: Does it also work when my data comes from an dataframe ?

Comment: if you need to update the dataframe directly then Jason Baker's answer above is what you need  but it is missing a to_list method call ```df.columns = df.iloc[0].to_list()``` and ```df = df.drop(df.index[0])```

Comment: already did that and still won't work